# Laravel validation mime-types tar.gz does not work

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.3, mime-types, tar

today was a trivial problem whith laravel validation. Upload file should have the appropriate mime-types.

In $_FILES:
[example.tar.gz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zuE1.png)

So i write into my rules:

```
return [
        'file' => 'required|mime_types: application/gzip' 
    ];
```

and have an error.

After that i went to Illuminate\Validation\Validator and try debugging method **validateMimetypes()** which returns **false**.

And then the most interesting, **$value->getMimeType()** return **"application/x-gzip"**

The question is where laravel take this "x-"?

PS: sorry for my English :)

Comment: You can also use like this: `"file" => "required|mimetypes:application/x-gzip|max:10000"` Or `"file" => "required|mimetypes:application/x-gzip|min:10000"`. Let me know if this work!!:)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
 return ['file' => 'required|mimetypes:application/x-gzip|min:2048'];
```